# ClickHouse. Как выбрать соседние записи по дате

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Как выбрать сгруппированные записи по логике: группировать записи, если разница между соседними датами не превышает 1 час.

Пример данных.

```
user_id    |       datetime      
    1      | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 12:40:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 14:10:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 14:20:00 
    1      | 2000-01-01 14:30:00
```

Результат запроса

```
user_id    |    start_datetime   |     end_datetime    | count  
    1      | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:40:00 |    3   
    1      | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 | 2000-01-01 14:30:00 |    4
```

Т.е. между двумя соседними датами `2000-01-01 12:40:00` и `2000-01-01 14:00:00`разница больше часа поэтому они должны попасть в разные группы.

Смотрел в сторону timeSlots, но либо не понял как использовать, либо это не то.

Comment: А если между 1 и 2 меньше, между 2 и 3 меньше, но между 1 и 3 больше (скажем, 0:00, 0:40, 1:20) - это одна группа?

Comment: Да это одна группа, ключевой момент, что записи отсортированы и разница должна браться только между двумя соседними.

Answer (score 1):

`timeSlots` подходят для группировки событий по заранее известным временным слотам (по умолчанию 30 минут). Это не твой случай.

В вопросе описан классический пример funnel анализа. Для этого в ClickHouse есть параметрические агрегатные функции, конкретно в данном случае пригодится [`windowFunnel(window)(timestamp, cond1, cond2, cond3, ...)`](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/query_language/agg_functions/parametric_functions/#windowfunnel-window-timestamp-cond1-cond2-cond3) или [`sequenceMatch(pattern)(time, cond1, cond2, ...)`](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/query_language/agg_functions/parametric_functions/#sequencematch-pattern-time-cond1-cond2)

Для вычисления count должно быть достаточно `windowFunnel(3600)(datetime)`, либо `sequenceMatch('(?1)(?2t<=3600)')(datetime)`

Comment: Ещё хотел поделиться полезной ссылкой по теме: [ClickHouse Meetup Berlin: Creating marketing funnels or how to calculate complex metrics in ClickHouse](https://events.yandex.com/lib/talks/247/)

Answer (score 0):

Решается с помощью функций runningDifference для выявления разницы между строками, if для установки флагов 0 или 1 если превышает указанное время. Далее runningAccumulate для присвоения каждой строке номера группы по флагу, и далее группировка по номеру группы GROUP BY